# Getting 'errno 38: function not implemented' while making a system call

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, intel

I'm trying to write a system call in Linux. I modified the `unistd.h`, `syscall_32.tbl` and `sys.c` as follows respectively:

```
/*
#define __NR3264_fadvise64 223
__SC_COMP(__NR3264_fadvise64, sys_fadvise64_64, compat_sys_fadvise64_64)
*/
#define __NR_zslhello 223
__SYSCALL(__NR_zslhello, sys_zslhello)
```

---

```
223 i386 zslhello sys_zslhello
```

---

```
asmlinkage int sys_zslhello(int ret)
{
    printk("Hello, my syscall!\n");
    return ret;
}
```

After compiling the kernel, I use `syscall(223, 10000);`, the return value is `-1`, and the `errno` is `38`, i.e., the *function is not implemented*. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: Are you compiling your code as a module? Did `make` targets did you run after modifying the code? I also think this should go to StackOverflow as it's clearly a programming question.

Comment: @SamiLaine I added a system call in the kernel code, and compiled the kernel. It's not a separate module.

Comment: Why do you comment out `sys_fadvise64_64`?Other parts of the kernel might rely on that....You should have it numbered $last_syscall_number + 1. In addition you might hit the fact that the system is 64 bit so you should change `syscall_64.tbl`.

Comment: And I warmly suggest you follow one of the many guides online to create it. You don't mention all the steps you followed as in other places: https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/ , https://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/ , https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/adding-syscalls.html .

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `syscall` was not implemented as the name suggests. Probably in your case your machine is a 64-bit one. So you have to change the file `syscall_64.tbl` not `syscall_32.tbl`.

In the last line of the file where the common syscalls are defined add a line

```
x common zslhello sys_zslhello
```

Where `x` is 1 plus the last value in common area. This is how a snippet of my `syscall_64.tbl` looks like.

```
330 common  pkey_alloc      sys_pkey_alloc
331 common  pkey_free       sys_pkey_free

#
# x32-specific system call numbers start at 512 to avoid cache impact
# for native 64-bit operation.
#
512 x32 rt_sigaction        compat_sys_rt_sigaction
513 x32 rt_sigreturn        sys32_x32_rt_sigreturn
```

In my case `x` is 332. Cheers!